# Energy Equation

Tags: radiation

I am reading a book on radiation and the author, while developing the equation of radiation transfer provides two forms of the equation, the second incidentally being more general and useful that the first:$$\rho C_v\frac{D T}{D t} =\nabla \cdot (k\nabla T) - p \nabla \cdot U - \nabla \cdot q_R $$ to $$  \rho C_p\frac{D T}{D t} =\nabla \cdot (k\nabla T) +  T\beta\frac{D P}{D t} - \nabla \cdot q_R$$
(Note: derivatives are material derivatives)

Question:

(1) How are these two forms equivalent?

(2) How is the second more useful?

Comment: Could you please tell me whether those equations are assumed for an ideal gas or fluid? What is beta by the way?

Comment: This is for a fluid element. Also, $\beta$ is the thermodynamic volumetric compressibility